# Why dns resolution isn't done over some secure protocol?

Tags: security, networking, dns, protocols

Why dns resolution doesn't use some secure protocol for security purposes. Isn't it a security concern if someone can see websites you are connecting with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.

Comment: Remember when DNS was invented. At that time, noone was snooping on things from others. The security model and constraints were far different than nowadays. And anyway you would need to specify more what you mean by "secure" and "security".  Authenticity is part of security, and this is solved with DNSSEC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a secured protocol - DNS over HTTPS.
Just recently it was added to some browsers as the default behavior.
You can read more about it at the wiki page - 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS

Comment: [DNS-over-HTTPS causes more problems than it solves, experts say](https://www.zdnet.com/article/dns-over-https-causes-more-problems-than-it-solves-experts-say/)

Comment: Or DNS over TLS, or DNS over QUIC soon.